# forward incoming traffic to local listener

Tags: networking, traffic-management

I have a service running on localhost which listens port localhost:10000

What I want to do is to forward all traffic coming to publicip:15000 to localhost:10000 where changing the configuration of service is not available.

Service only listens localhost, however traffic comes from outside.

Service runs on linux by the way.

Edit; I tried to add NAT rule like this but I could not be successful.

To configure NAT I did;

```
iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface lo -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o lo -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i lo -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
service ufw restart
```

And to start routing execute this;

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 15000 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:10000
```

What do you think I am missing ?

Thanks in advance

Baris

Comment: And what type of application is listening on localhost:10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that DNAT for loopback traffic is not possible.

Loopback traffic skip both PREROUTING and OUTPUT chains.

[RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) (page 3) says that network `127.0.0.0/8` could not be routed outside of the host itself :

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host
> loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an
> address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host.  This
> is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback.  As
> described in [RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3, addresses within the entire
> 127.0.0.0/8 block do not legitimately appear on any network anywhere.

---

Also, traffic to `loopback interface` are considered as `Martian Packets` :

> these packets cannot actually originate as claimed, or be delivered

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_packet

---

**Workaround :**

A simple alternative is to use an `inted` server on Server side, and its `redirect`  feature.

This way, you can define un service within `inetd` and set the port where this service will listen to. Then, set the `redirect` directive to bind this port to `127.0.0.1:port`.

In my sample below i will use `xinetd` (on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) to bind a `mysql` server running on `127.0.0.1:10000` :

**Step 1 :** Install the package : `apt-get install xinetd`

**Step 2 :** Edit de the config file `/etc/xinetd.conf`

Add a service definition similar to the one below :

```
service my_redirector
{
 type = UNLISTED
 disable = no
 socket_type = stream
 protocol = tcp
 user = root
 wait = no
 port = 15000
 redirect = 127.0.0.1 10000
 log_type = FILE /tmp/somefile.log
}
```

**Step 3 :** Restart `xinetd` daemon : `service xinetd restart`

**Step 4 :** let's check for the listener on port `15000` :

```
# netstat -anp | grep 15000
tcp     0      0 0.0.0.0:15000      0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      4654/xinetd
```

**Step 5 :** Add your `iptables` rules :

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -d 192.168.0.60 --dport 15000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.0.60 --sport 15000 -j ACCEPT
```

---

**Let's test it :**

For testing i have setup `mysql` to listen on `127.0.0.1:10000`. I will try to access it through the `xinetd` service on port `15000`.

First, on Server side, i make sure that `mysql` server is only listening on `127.0.0.1:10000` :

```
# netstat -anp | grep :10000
tcp    0    0 127.0.0.1:10000    0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      4247/mysqld
```

Then, on Client side, let's check if we can connect using port `15000` :

```
# telnet 192.168.0.60 15000
Trying 192.168.0.60...
Connected to 192.168.0.60.
Escape character is '^]'.
_
5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-logD46S}<P`.6cr4ITIQ<wcmysql_native_password
```

Seems we can ! :)

Let's try to connect to `mysql` server :

```
# mysql -h 192.168.0.60 --port=15000 -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 67
Server version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Done !

Comment: Thank you user :) That was what I did yesterday but as you have given the same working answer I marked as correct :) Thank you very much :)